# For loop not met?

Tags: java, for-loop

So i'm trying to write this code which goes into another class to store info but i have a problem with the for loop and i dont know why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> Teams = new ArrayList();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Please Enter how many teams?\n");
        int x;
        x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print(x);
        for ( int i=0 ; i>=x ; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("Enter the %s Team\n", x);
                String temp;
                temp = input.next();
                Team TeamNamee = new Team(temp);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop should be

```
 for ( int i=0 ; i<=x ; i++)
```

`i` is less than equal to `x`

**Understanding Loop:**

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //Statements
}
```

> The **initialization step** is executed first, and only once. This step
>   allows you to declare and initialize any loop control variables. You
>   are not required to put a statement here, as long as a semicolon
>   appears.
>
> Next, the **Boolean expression** is evaluated. If it is true, the body of
>   the loop is executed. If it is false, the body of the loop does not
>   execute and flow of control jumps to the next statement past the for
>   loop.
>
> After the body of the for loop executes, the flow of control jumps
>   back up to the **update** statement. This statement allows you to update
>   any loop control variables. This statement can be left blank, as long
>   as a semicolon appears after the Boolean expression.

So in your case(Boolean expression is false) `i` is not greater than or equal to x(if x is greater than 0 ) for loop is not executed.

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)

Comment: And note that if x < 0 it leads to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Change your for loop like this:

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<=x ; i++)
```

instead of

```
for ( int i=0 ; i>=x ; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for ( int i=0 ; i>=x ; i++)
```

to

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<=x ; i++)
```

so the for loops runs as long as i is smaller or equal to x

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=x; i>=0; i--)
```

if you want to use 'greater than' in the condition part.

Answer (score 1):

Loop must be:

```
  for (int i = 1 ; i <= x ; i++)
```

if you want start numbering from 1, or

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
```

if you prefer numbering from 0 (in your current loop condition `i>=x` is never `true` if `x > 0`, so your loop never works).

Also expression

```
  System.out.printf("Enter the %s Team\n", x);
```

looks strange inside the loop, so consider the following

```
  System.out.printf("Enter the %d's Team\n", i);
```

and for that output numbering from 1 (the first option concerning `for`) looks seems to be better.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to:
`for(int i = 0; i<=x; i++)
{
}`

instead of:
`for ( int i=0 ; i>=x ; i++)
{
}`